# How to get nested directives work in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular js a bit and came across http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/.  I was trying to implement similar to that and I have my directives defined as follows (message1, message2 and message3 have same code):

```
 <pre>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('msg', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.a = 5; 
    }]);

    app.directive('message1', function($interpolate){
        return{
            template: '<div> a = {{a}} </div>',

            compile: function(tElement, tAttributes){ 
                console.log(tAttributes.text + " -In compile..");

                return {

                    pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, controller){
                        console.log(iAttributes.text + " -In pre..");
                    },

                    post: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, controller){
                        console.log(iAttributes.text + " -In Post..");
                    }

                }
            },

            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                console.log($attrs.text + " -In controller..");
            },

        }
    });



    app.directive('message2', function($interpolate){
        return{
            template: '<div> a = {{a}} </div>',

            compile: function(tElement, tAttributes){ 
                console.log(tAttributes.text + " -In compile..");

                return {
                    pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, controller){
                        console.log(iAttributes.text + " -In pre..");
                    },

                    post: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, controller){
                        console.log(iAttributes.text + " -In Post..");
                    }

                }
            },

            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                console.log($attrs.text + " -In controller..");
            },

        }
    });

    app.directive('message3', function($interpolate){
        return{
            template: '<div> a = {{a}} </div>',

            compile: function(tElement, tAttributes){ 
                console.log(tAttributes.text + " -In compile..");

                return {
                    pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, controller){
                        console.log(iAttributes.text + " -In pre..");
                    },

                    post: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, controller){
                        console.log(iAttributes.text + " -In Post..");
                    }

                }
            },

            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                console.log($attrs.text + " -In controller..");
            },

        }
    });
    </pre>
```

My html as follows:

```
        <body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="msg">
            <div message1 text="first">
                <div message2 text="..second">
                    <div message3 text="....third">

                    </div>              
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    The console gives the following output:

    [![enter image description here][1]][1]

    What I would like to see is the following:

    <pre>
    first -In Compile..
    ..second -In Compile..
    ....third -In Compile..
    first -In Controller..
    first -In Pre..
    ..second -In Controller..
    ..second -In Pre..
    ....third -In Controller..
    ....third -In Pre..
    ....third -In Post..
    ..second -In Post..
    first -In Post..
    </pre>


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGApa.png
```

Comment: You're overwriting the contents of `<div message1...>` with its `template`. Use [transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) to take them into account or get rid of `template`.

Comment: Got it.  Even with transclusion, I get "In Compile" in reverse (i.e., third, second and first).  Is that an expected behavior?

Comment: No, it isn't expected, [it should be fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/4FAfcdWPqtDjGjayPxDu?p=preview). Can you replicate the issue as fiddle/plunk?